# How can I apply a class from one directive to another in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add a class from `toggleClass` directive to `Header` directive without using a jQuery selector? Not sure how I can do this in AngularJS, is directive to directive communication needed in this case?

```
<Header></Header>

<toggleClass></toggleClass>
```

in toggleClass directive I have:

```
module.exports = Directive;
function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/directive.html',
    link : function(scope, element){
          scope.expandToggle = function() {
            // add class to Header directive
          } 
    }
  }
};
```

and its template:

```
<div ng-click="expandToggle()">
  <span class="collapseText">Collapse</span>
  <span class="expandText">Expand</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use ng-class in the Header directive (you should create a custom header directive) and depending on a variable you enable the class you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1'st way: use $emit

You can `$emit` event from `toggleClass` directive to parent controller, and change boolean value to control adding/removing your class.

**ToggleClass directive:**

```
module.exports = Directive;
function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/vic-compare-quotes-expand/templates/directive.html',
    link : function(scope, element){
          scope.expandToggle = function() {
            scope.$emit('toggle');
          } 
    }
  }
};
```

**Parent controller:**

```
angular
  .module('yourModule')
  .controller('YourController', ['$scope', YourController]);

function YourController($scope) {
  $scope.$on('toggle', function() {
    $scope.apllyNeededClass = true;
  })
}
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<Header ng-class="{'classToApply': apllyNeededClass}"></Header>

<toggleClass></toggleClass>
```

### 2'nd way: use service

You can use services for sharing data between controllers (directive and controller in your case).

**ToggleClass directive:**

```
module.exports = Directive;
function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/vic-compare-quotes-expand/templates/directive.html',
    link : function(scope, element){
          scope.expandToggle = function() {
            yourService.apllyNeededClass = true;
            // don't forget to inject "yourService" in this directive
          } 
    }
  }
};
```

**Parent controller:**

```
angular
  .module('yourModule')
  .controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'yourService', YourController]);

function YourController($scope, yourService) {     
  $scope.apllyNeededClass = yourService.apllyNeededClass;
  // bind service variable to your $scope variable
}
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<Header ng-class="{'classToApply': apllyNeededClass}"></Header>

<toggleClass></toggleClass>
```

### P.S.

I'm using `ng-class` on `<Header>` tag just for example and because I don't know the template of your `Header` directive.

Comment: Nice. What about directive to directive communication through creating an API? That seems a lot more easier to track and test.

Comment: Directive controllers are controllers too. Why don't you want to use services for sharing data between them?

Comment: I think that what @Nima means is that there is one more way to do it: expose an API (through the controller), then inject it into the other directive with `require` and consume it. Like here: https://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/directive-to-directive-communication.html

Comment: And BTW in case of communicating through a service I'd suggest a little bit better API with service::toggleClass() (for the class toggle initiatior) and service::onClassToggleRequested(cb) (for the class toggle listener) methods. Which in fact is very similar the to event-based $emit scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand correctly at first. I don't know another way, but let me stay my answer here, may be someone will find it useful for his/her case

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Easy, no one is saying you should remove the answer:)